# createVNode is not a function (Vue with Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a component render as per an example I found online.

I created a sample project and it works fine there, but it crashes when I'm trying to use the same thing on the official code base.

here is the contents of the blade file which is rendered.

```php
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue SPA Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        asdfsadfsadsdf
        <example-component></example-component>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then, here is app.js

```js
window.Vue = require("vue").default;
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

Vue.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
```

and here is ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>Example Component</div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

here is what the page looks like:
[image]

and here is the error:
[image]

Fun fact: when I try to include the component like this instead, it displays "Test" as expected

```js
Vue.component('example-component', {
    template: '<div>Test</div>'
});
```

so it is clear to me that this line/file is the issue

```js
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!! After almost 8 hours...

[image]

Turns out the "vue-loader" 16.1.2 from `package.json` was the mistake. I tried the exact same configuration but changed "16.1.2" to "15.9.2" and vice-versa 4-5 times and running

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

in-between every package change.

Fun fact: after that, your component will render when you write

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

in your app.js